# PHP wrap generated content in something

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$fh = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
$pageText = fread($fh, 25000);
echo nl2br($pageText);
```

With a test text document having the content:

```
a
b
c c c c
>>this should be highlighted>>
```

How would I go about adding `<span class="highlight">...</span>` around the text within `>>...>>` and replacing the `>>`.

Thanks.

Comment: One solution is `preg_replace` with a pattern `@>>.*?>>@`.

Comment: @StanislavShabalin `preg_replace('@>>.*?>>@','<span>.*?</span>',$pageText);` something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the PREG_REPLACE command to replace the wanted string with the tags you need like:

```
echo nl2br(preg_replace('/(>>)([^\>>]*)(>>)/', 
                           '<span class="highlight">$2</span>',
                           $pageText );
```

See it here on regex101: http://regex101.com/r/rM7vP9/1